# Poisson distribution - Number of accidents

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I need help with this probability problem.

> The number of fatal car accidents that happen in a specific region
>   **follows the Poisson distribution with a rate of 0.5 fatal car
>   accidents per day**
>
> (a) What is the probability that a fatal car accident will happen in
>   the next 2 days and after that accident within no more than one day,
>   the next fatal car accident occurs?
>
> (b) Calculate (approximately) the probability to wait more than 60
>   days for the occurrence of the 40th fatal car accident.

My solution is the following.

(a) Firstly I calculate the probability that a fatal car accident will happen in 2 days.

$0.5$ car accidents happen in $1$ day, so $1$ accident happens in $2$ days. That means that my new rate is $λ=1$. Considering the random variable

$$X=\text{number of car accidents}$$

we have that $X$ follows $\operatorname{Poisson}(λ=1)$.
As a result, $P(X=1)=0.3679$.

Next, I consider a random variable $Z=\text{number of days until the next car accident}.$ Then, Z follows $\operatorname{Geo}(p=0.3679)$ (I am not sure about the $p$). As a result, $P(Z\le1)=0.3679$.

To calculate the asked probability I simply multiply the above probabilities:
$P(X=1)\cdot P(Z\le1)$.

(b) I consider the random variable $Y=\text{number of days till the 40th car accident}$
Then $Y$ follows $\operatorname{Negative Binomial}(k=40,p=0.3679)$ and the asked probability is $P(Y>60)$.

Is my solution right? What is your opinion?

Comment: NB in public health policy and underwriting, these are not called "accidents" or at least they shouldn't be. Rather, they are collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Actually I am not an English native speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inter-arrival times between independent Poisson events are exponentially distributed, with $\lambda=0.5$ (in days), i.e. $\mu=\frac{1}{\lambda}=2$. Let $T_1$ be the time (in days) of the first fatal accident, and $T_2$ be the extra time needed for the next fatal accident. In (a), we need to calculate $P(T_1<2, T_2<1)$ $=P(T_1<2)$ $ P(T_2<1)$. Each $T_i$ is exponentially distributed. You can substitute this: $P(T<t)=1-e^{\lambda t}$. Be careful while changing your $\lambda$.

Comment: I agree with your solution. Is $λ=2$ in both $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: Yes, because you have a stationary process.